# Creating a low power, high AC current using a current transformer?

Tags: current, transformer, electromagnetism, current-transformer

I want to create 0-32A AC to *test* 1:2000 current transformers with. Create the current in a rough way, use a scope probe to measure RMS and verify calibration of current transformer circuit under test.

And I am playing with the idea to create high currents using a similar current transformer, but reversed. With 10mA say 5V AC on the 2000 winding side hoping to get 2000x the current when I put single copper wire through it with short circuited ends.

Could that possibly have a current start flowing through the copper wire at an extremely low (1/2000th?) voltage?

A similar question I couldn’t answer is what happens if you want to make a transformer with a massive copper core and two 2000 winding coils at each end. It shouldn’t work since magnetically it is all a nightmare. But I just wonder.

Comment: A core made of copper is a foolish thing seemingly.

Comment: Since copper is about as magnetically permeable as air (compared to iron anyway) it wouldn't work any better than an air-cored transformer, but with added weight and expense.

Comment: Aside from the fact that a copper core has low magnetic permeability, as already mentioned, it would also suffer terribly from eddy currents. Iron and steel cores are laminated precisely to reduce the flow of eddy currents.

Comment: I think the idea of using a similar current transformer is viable, but you need to get your numbers right.

Comment: Charles Cowie, how would I do that?